# Webfaction subdomain down on some machines

Tags: django

I have two domains and (ideally) a subdomain for one of them running on different django apps running on the same webfaction server.  I can navigate to both the domains but pinging the subdomain often fails and seems to vary from time to time and from machine to machine.  Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

This question should really be directed to Webfaction support--if there's a problem, it's almost certainly in your configurations in the Webfaction panel, and they'll be much better able to help you than us.  They've also been universally polite and competent in my experience.